# Get Response From External App in Windows Workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

i am working on one small app i.e workflow wcf service which takes input of array of email and parallelforeach is sending email to each email id. in email i am sending two links for approval and decline which should call my MVC web application controller.controller calls my methods in workflow service for remaining execution.there is a console application which initiate a request of sending mail. mail sent successfully but when i click on the link given in the mail for approval or decline it does not work ! please suggest me something..

Comment: Writing the perfect question. http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: What is the link in the email? Is it pointing to an internal or external address? Are you opening the email internally on your network or externally?